# Record Layout File with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using US Census data, which I downloaded using [DataFerrett](http://dataferrett.census.gov/). When I selected the data format, I chose space delimited data files. The data ferret gave me two files to download:

- Space Delimited ASCII File
- Record Layout File

How do I use this Record Layout File? The contents looks like

```
HRHHID     1   15 C 
HRHHID2   17   24 C 
OCCURNUM  26   33 B 
YYYYMM    35   42 B 
HES6O     44   51 B 
HES2O     53   60 B 
HES3O     62   69 B 
HES4O     71   78 B 
HES5O     80   87 B 
HES7O     89   96 B 
PULINENO  98  105 B 
HHSUPWGT 107  115 I 
HWHHWGT  117  125 I 
PWSSWGT  127  135 I
```

Here's how the data looks:

```
         HRHHID  HRHHID2 OCCURNUM   YYYYMM    HES6O    HES2O    HES3O    HES4O    HES5O    HES7O PULINENO  HHSUPWGT   HWHHWGT   PWSSWGT 
064924107035109    82001        1   200612       16      200       20       -1       -1       -1        1 2892.4085 2345.5278 2345.5278 
064924107035109    82001        2   200612       16      200       20       -1       -1       -1        2 2892.4085 2345.5278 2267.5849 
910114009306600    80001        1   200612       25       40       18       10        0       -1        1 3805.3921 3193.3556 3193.3556 
076240110692093    81001        1   200612       -1       -1       -1       -1       -1       -1        1    0.0000 3373.2932 3373.2932
```

Where the first is a variable name, I suppose the second and third are the character numbers at which the value starts and ends - I have no clue what the last character denotes.

How can I load the data using `pandas`? [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-read-csv-table) doesn't appear to support adding a record layout file. I tried adding `sep=' '`, but that leads to an error. And if I just load it without using the record file or any specific modification, it doesn't seem to be dealing with the spaces well:

```
>>> test = pd.read_csv('myfile')
>>> test.head()
           HRHHID  HRHHID2 OCCURNUM   YYYYMM    HES6O    HES2O    HES3O    HES4O    HES5O    HES7O PULINENO  HHSUPWGT   HWHHWGT   PWSSWGT 
0  064924107035109    82001        1   200612    ...                                                                                      
1  064924107035109    82001        2   200612    ...                                                                                      
2  910114009306600    80001        1   200612    ...                                                                                      
3  076240110692093    81001        1   200612    ...                                                                                      
4  891269120116007    82001        1   200612    ...                                                                                      
>>> test.columns
Index([u'         HRHHID  HRHHID2 OCCURNUM   YYYYMM    HES6O    HES2O    HES3O    HES4O    HES5O    HES7O PULINENO  HHSUPWGT   HWHHWGT   PWSSWGT '], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the file? The record layout seems to be indicating the location of fixed-width columns. If so, you could use `pd.read_fwf`.

Comment: I added both samples now.

Comment: @unutbu that worked like a charm. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Interestingly, just using `read_fwf` was sufficient - I didn't need to use the record layout file at all.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just download the data as Comma Delimited, then `read_csv()` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read fixed-width formatted lines into a DataFrame, use [`pd.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html).
You can use the `colspecs` parameter to define the extent of the fixed-width fields. If you don't specify `colspecs`, `read_fwf` will try to infer the location of the columns.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
try: from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError: from io import Stringio

text = '''         HRHHID  HRHHID2 OCCURNUM   YYYYMM    HES6O    HES2O    HES3O    HES4O    HES5O    HES7O PULINENO  HHSUPWGT   HWHHWGT   PWSSWGT 
064924107035109    82001        1   200612       16      200       20       -1       -1       -1        1 2892.4085 2345.5278 2345.5278 
064924107035109    82001        2   200612       16      200       20       -1       -1       -1        2 2892.4085 2345.5278 2267.5849 
910114009306600    80001        1   200612       25       40       18       10        0       -1        1 3805.3921 3193.3556 3193.3556 
076240110692093    81001        1   200612       -1       -1       -1       -1       -1       -1        1    0.0000 3373.2932 3373.2932 '''

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(text))
print(df)
```

yields

```
            HRHHID  HRHHID2  OCCURNUM  YYYYMM  HES6O  HES2O  HES3O  HES4O  \
0   64924107035109    82001         1  200612     16    200     20     -1   
1   64924107035109    82001         2  200612     16    200     20     -1   
2  910114009306600    80001         1  200612     25     40     18     10   
3   76240110692093    81001         1  200612     -1     -1     -1     -1   

   HES5O  HES7O  PULINENO   HHSUPWGT    HWHHWGT    PWSSWGT  
0     -1     -1         1  2892.4085  2345.5278  2345.5278  
1     -1     -1         2  2892.4085  2345.5278  2267.5849  
2      0     -1         1  3805.3921  3193.3556  3193.3556  
3     -1     -1         1     0.0000  3373.2932  3373.2932
```

---

This might work for data which does not include spaces. In general, you may need to use the record-layout to find the correct column specs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import operator

colspecs = []
with open('record-layout.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        # subtract 1 since Python uses 0-based indexing; record-layout uses
        # 1-based indexing.
        # Do not reduce row[2] since read_fwf uses half-open intervals and 
        # the record-layout is using closed intervals.
        colspecs.append([int(row[1])-1, int(row[2])])


df = pd.read_fwf('data', colspecs=colspecs)
print(df)
```